# URL alias to call function

Tags: uri, path-aliases

in short I want the same functionality as the taxonomy module where you can have an URL like "localhost/drupal/admin/structure/taxonomy/occupational_fields/edit"
where occupational_fields was the aliased part.

The menu entry in taxonomy for the page callback looks like this:

```
$items['admin/structure/taxonomy/%taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name/edit'] = array(
  'title' => 'Edit',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('taxonomy_form_vocabulary', 3),
  'access arguments' => array('administer taxonomy'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'weight' => -10,
  'file' => 'taxonomy.admin.inc',
);
```

The function declaration looks like this:

```
function taxonomy_form_vocabulary($form, &$form_state, $edit = array())
```

Now my implementation looks like this:

```
$items['admin/config/mapper/%tid/edit'] = array(
  'title'            => 'Mapper edit mapping',
  'description'      => 'Add or edit a mapping',
  'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments'   => array('mapper_form_mappings', 3),
  'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
  'type'             => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'file'             => 'mapper.admin.inc',
);
```

And respectively:

```
function mapper_form_mappings($form, &$form_state, $edit = array())
```

But when an URL like "localhost/drupal/admin/config/mapper/11/edit" is opened
the function above is not called.

I tried googling a good URL alias tutorial for module programming, but couldn't find one. Maybe I searched for the wrong thing?

edit: I can imagine that I need some type of handler, but I couldn't find one in the taxonomy files and the tutorials didn't mention them either.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me, cleared the caches, checked the menu_router for the new path, all was there. Can you clear all caches and check for the entry in that table (menu_router) ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll do some more tests then, just for clarification, does the placeholder ( in my case %tid ) have any significance? Or could I also write %something instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is a proper answer to a tricky question.

### Documentation

First of all, you should read the following two documents, if you haven't already:

- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x
- https://www.drupal.org/node/224170

### Simple Wildcards

By using % as a path wildcard you are instructing the menu_router matching algorithm to use the path argument as it is (used mostly for numerical arguments). So, following from your comment, yes, it does have a significance. If you write your code like this:

```
$items['admin/config/mapper/%/edit'] = array(
  'title'            => 'Mapper edit mapping',
  'description'      => 'Add or edit a mapping',
  'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments'   => array('mapper_form_mappings', 3),
  'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
  'type'             => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'file'             => 'mapper.admin.inc',
);
```

you are going to get the 3rd part of your path as an argument to your mapper_form_mappings function. Exactly as it occurs in the path.

### Auto-Loader Wildcards

Now, if you would use a `%NAME` type of wildcard, like taxonomy does, you would be triggering the ['Autoloader Wildcards'](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x#sub_autoload_wildcards) (a.k.a. ['Wildcard Loader Arguments'](https://www.drupal.org/node/224170#page-subtitle)) functionality. Drupal will try to load an object through a function called `NAME_load`. In the case of the `%taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name` Drupal will try to load a vocabulary using the specified machine name as an argument to the [`taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load/7.x) function. The loaded object will then be passed as an argument to [`drupal_get_form`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7.x) (or any other function defined in your path definition).

### Current problem

In your case, your original code:

```
$items['admin/config/mapper/%tid/edit'] = array(
  'title'            => 'Mapper edit mapping',
  'description'      => 'Add or edit a mapping',
  'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments'   => array('mapper_form_mappings', 3),
  'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
  'type'             => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'file'             => 'mapper.admin.inc',
);
```

implies there is a `tid_load` function that will receive the `%tid` argument from the URL and should return some object to `drupal_get_form`. This is however not working, since such a function does not exist.

### Alternatives using wildcard loaders

If you want to use the 'Auto-Loader Wildcards' functionality, you should do one of the following:

- Use an existing _load function, e.g. [`taxonomy_term_load`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7.x). Your wildcard should be called `%taxonomy_term` in this case and the final argument passed to drupal_get_form would be an taxonomy term object.
- Use a custom _load function, e.g. `mapper_load`. Your wildcard should be called `%mapper` in this case and the final argument passed to `drupal_get_form` would be whatever your `mapper_load` function returns.

Best of luck!

Comment: Wow, huge thanks for this awesome little tutorial! I wish there were more like these for core drupal features. I really struggle to find on-point instructions most of the time or don't know what exact to search for. The first link had most if this I see, I just haven't found it :(

Comment: Very welcome, a pleasure to run this through my head too. Practice makes perfect, see you around!